# Cannot import module from source directory in pycharm

Tags: import, module, pycharm, python-3.6

This question has been asked before - but i could not solve it with any of the answers. I opned a project folder in pycharm (*note* that the project folder is not in the `../PycharmProject/...` directory.

My structure is super basic:

```
project_title (folder)
             |--src (folder)
                  |-- app.py  
                  |-- pipeline_tools (folder)
                     |-- helpers.py
                     |-- other modules
```

I tried all possible solutions and combinations but when in `app.py` i try to import a function from either modules in `tools` I get errors.

Additionally, Pycharm underlines in red the following statement:

1) `from pipeline_tools.helpers import a_certain_function` (red underline with "Unresolved reference")

But the following gives me no red:

2) `from .pipeline_tools.helpers import a_certain_function` (no red underline, note the relative import)

The fact that I have or not a `__init__.py` inside the modules changes nothing - I still get the following two errors:

For 1)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gabriele/pycharm-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipeline_tools'
```

for 2)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gabriele/pycharm-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.pipeline_tools'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Stuff I made sure I tried:

1) Go to `settings > Project Structure` check `content root` is `.../project_title` and marked it as "source" - it's blue.

2) Add `__init__.py` in the `pipeline_tools` folder and in the `/src` folder, tried all possible combinations.

3) Use the below code to check the path to the project folder is part of the path string - it is **at the end**

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

4) Use the below code to move the project path to the beginning of the sys.path:
`sys.path.insert(0,'path/to/project_title')`

5) Just tried to print `PYTHONPATH` like this:

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
```

and the **directory of my project is not in it**

I am a bit at a loss right now. Have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some frigging reason i don't understand setting the `src` directory as my source `sources root` instead of the `project_title` directory (which contains it anyways...but what do I know) worked.

So solution was:

-> settings 
  -> project structure 
                      -> remove previous content root path and make content source the `src` directory

import like this:

`from pipeline_tools.helpers import func_1, func_2`

**Note:** that i **do not** have a `__init__.py` file in my folder, as I believe i read they're not necessary anymore.

> Prior to Python 3.3, filesystem directories, and directories within zipfiles, had to contain an **init**.py in order to be recognised as Python package directories. Even if there is no initialisation code to run when the package is imported, an empty **init**.py file is still needed for the interpreter to find any modules or subpackages in that directory.
>
> This has changed in Python 3.3: now any directory on sys.path with a name that matches the package name being looked for will be recognised as contributing modules and subpackages to that package.

From [Nick Coghlan’s Python Notes](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html)

Comment: If `project_title` was your source your imports should look like: `from src.pipeline_tools.helpers import myfunction`. As you write your imports as `from pipeline_tools....` you implicitly assume that you sources root is `src`, that's why when you define `src` as such` it works. One quick way of setting this up is to right click on the folder you want to be you sources root and to click `Mark directory as -> Sources root`. The directory should then appear in blue color in the tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation!  "As you write your imports as from pipeline_tools.... you implicitly assume that you sources root is `src`" Does this mean that with `project_title` as sources I could have simply written `from helpers import func`?

Comment: No, you need to precise the path from the root you choose. So if it is the top folder, you would need to write `from src.pipeline_tools.helpers import func`. However, I suggest that you choose `src` for the Sources Root as it seems more natural given how the tree looks like.

Comment: This worked for me. Setting the `src` directory as the Sources folder is what I needed.